# clx/vcl incompatibility

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

I have inherited an application that was built in Delphi, using clx components (TcxMaskEdit, TcxCurrencyEdit).  I cannot open this application because I lack the clx components in my copy of Delphi.  If I ignore the warning messages, the application opens without those components on the forms and the Win32 library disappears.  I cannot get these components because they are no longer carried by the original developer.  So, this leaves me with two options: either find a way to get the clx components, or convert them to vcl.  The application has had so many man hours devoted to it and is so business critical that it cannot be easily re-written or replaced.  So, my question is: how can I convert the clx components to vcl or otherwise obtain these deprecated components?  Or is there something here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TcxMaskEdit` and `TCxCurrencyEdit` are not CLX controls. They're part of the older [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com) components (not sure if they're still around or not). In order to open your project, you'll need to get a copy of whatever version your application used. You'll need to ask the old developer what that was, or contact DevEx support and see if they can help you.

(The CLX components have the same name as their VCL counterparts. The only difference is the unit names in the uses clause of your source; the VCL `Dialogs` unit is replaced by `QDialogs`, `Forms` becomes `QForms`, and so forth. Switching from CLX to VCL is as easy as searching for any unit starting with `Q`, and removing that single letter if there's a corresponding VCL unit, and then rebuilding your app.)

Comment: And yes, DevEx is still around and kickin. You might buy some of their components and try to build with them. If your code is really old you might get some compatibility issues. If you want more advice on which DevEx packages to buy, provide DevEx or us with a list of the Tcx... types used in your code.

Comment: They also released soem of their older libraries as free `DevExpress Forum` though i don't know if aforementioned components are in the list

Comment: @JanDoggen: I'm well aware DevEx is still around; as I said, the poster should contact **DevEx support**, and I provided a link to their web site. ;-) My comment was related to whether the `Tcx*` flavor of components are still around, because everything now is `Tdx*`. But thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: Thanks for that info. I didn't know about the freeware release of the older stuff.

Comment: I see DexEx trend to change dx prefix t ocx one. Quantum TreeList, Quantum Grid - they are of cx fame now

Comment: Update, I tried Ken's solution of removing the Q's from my code.  This appeared to work.  Then I got an error stating that I needed to install cxControls.dcu.  Did so, now I need to install FileControls.dcu, but can't find it on my computer nor can I find where to download.  I wish it would tell me everything that I need to fix at once rather than one at a time, so I could get to the end of this and see if Ken's solution actually did work.

Comment: Edit, FileControls.dcu should be FileCtrls.dcu

Comment: Matt, you didn't read my answer carefully enough. The `Tcx` and `cx` files are part of a component set (see my *first paragraph above*). I **did indeed** tell you everything at once - we have no way of knowing what other issues you might run into until you tell us, and those would go in different (new) questions.

Comment: Ken, DevExpress has informed us that they no longer support anything going back that far in terms of dcu.  I will just have to hope that the original developer has the file on their machine.  Thanks for your help.  Accepting as answer.

Comment: @Arioch'The: No, I'm afraid you have it backward. They've gotten rid of `cx` and changed everything to `dx` (they did this several years ago).

Comment: since i am transferring application from Quantum * 3.x to current Quantum * 6.x - i know better :-) At least for unit names. Well, let's guess they bring some order into previous wild mix, they have soem idea to separate dx and cx and they are pushing it, so in some places there is one directin, and in another there may be opposite one. like `In the dxCore unit, the cxBinToHex and cxHexToBin functions have been renamed dxBinToHex and dxHexToBin, respectively.`

Comment: this looks to me that they strive for uniformity and probably some day ago those constants were is some dx* unit, then unit got renamed and finally constants are renamed too.
Or maybe you're working with DevEx .NET suite rather than VCL ? look at a lot of cx prefixes in http://pastebin.ca/2291454 http://pastebin.ca/2291455